# How can I process FileNotFoundException ?

Tags: android

recently

I try A.txt file read content.

but if my device have not a.txt , occur FileNotFoundException

so I want  if my device have not a.txt, How can i stay to proceed?

```
String path = "/sdcard/Download";
    String textName = "a.txt";

    String serverVersion = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = BufferedReaderFactory.create(path, textName);

        StringBuilder contentGetter = new StringBuilder();
        while ((serverVersion = br.readLine()) != null) {

            serverVersion = serverVersion.trim().toLowerCase();
            contentGetter.append('\n' + serverVersion);
            Log.d(TAG, " myServerVersion = " + serverVersion);
            break;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple create a variable before try/catch like

```
boolean isFileFound = false;
```

So, at the final of the try you set `isFileFound = true` 
like:

```
String path = "/sdcard/Download";
    String textName = "a.txt";

    boolean isFileFound = false;

    String serverVersion = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = BufferedReaderFactory.create(path, textName);

        StringBuilder contentGetter = new StringBuilder();
        while ((serverVersion = br.readLine()) != null) {

            serverVersion = serverVersion.trim().toLowerCase();
            contentGetter.append('\n' + serverVersion);
            Log.d(TAG, " myServerVersion = " + serverVersion);
            break;
        }
        isFileFound = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!isFileFound){ // This is equals to if(isFileFound != null)
        //Do some message here, like:
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.    and I have 1 question.   if(isFileFound) { what is in content ?

Comment: I don't understand why add isFileFound ?

Comment: I've changed the conditional (if) to if (isFileFound != null) or if(!isFileFound). You can put some message, anything... or just ignore( you don't need the if) but if you don't use any condition you don't need the variable isFileFound. This variable just say "Hey, i'm execute all try content with no errors"

Comment: The variable isFileFound is just a track to tell you if all try block works fine.

Comment: Because you use the serverVersion inside try block. If it recive a value, it won't be anymore a null variable and you still can got a exception. So if you check if(serverVersion == null) the conditional is false, but you can't say that all try block runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already handling the exception. If there is no file your code will continue as planned. After your try/catch blocks, you should check `if(serverVersion == null)` and if it returns true, you know that the serverVersion was not read from the file.

Comment: I try `else if (serverVersion != indeviceVersion || serverVersion.equals(null))`  add compareVersion part. but .. same here

Comment: ah, now you have a NullPointerException because you're trying to use `.equals()` on a null value
update:
Try this `else if (serverVersion == null || !serverVersion.equals(indeviceVersion))`

Notice how I used `serverVersion.equals()` *after* `serverVersion == null`. This does not return a null pointer exception, because if `serverVersion == null`, the rest of the if statement is ignored.

Comment: sorry?  I try `else if (serverVersion ==null || !serverVersion.equals(indeviceVersi)) {  but same exception . .. sorry